# Best input to connect a monitor to a Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I just bought a 24" monitor (asus pa246q) with dvi/hdmi/displayport inputs. I am wondering which is the best input I should use to connect a MacBook Pro 15" (late 2010). Someone suggested me HDMI, but the image is not perfect, still looks better on my old white-plastic Cinema Display with ADC adapter.

I was thinking to display port as an obvious solution, but I have to find a mini display port to display port adapter.

Any suggestion? thanks

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with DisplayPort, if for no other reason than it's the native connector for your MacBook, and it's more likely that other devices will have DVI or HDMI, so that if you feel the need to use multiple computers with the monitor in the future you have those ports open.

[Monoprice](http://www.monoprice.com) is my go-to source for cabling. It has a pretty good selection of DisplayPort (mini and full-size) cables and adapters, very cheaply, including  the [mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort cables](http://www.monoprice.com/products/subdepartment.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10246#1024606) you need.